# search of .xml files without certain tag through mac os terminal

Tags: command-line, macos, search, xml

I would appreciate having your advice on the below.

Having a folder name "ABC" with thousands of .xml files inside. The core structure of XMLs is the same:

```
<product abcd…>
  <category>
  ...
  </category>
</product>
```

Some xml files can be considered as *valid* as these contains a required `<category>` tag) some of these are *invalid* as the required `<category>` tag is completely missing. It even doesn't have a closing `</category>`

So the goal is to find via terminal those 'invalid' xmls without `</category>` tag inside XML placed in the "ABC" folder.

Any chance?

Comment: Are all files, invalid or not, still well-formed XML documents?

Comment: Is `category` supposed to always be a child-node of `product`? Or can it occur anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all XML files are well-formed: Using `xmlstarlet`, the following prints the input filename of any file that does *not* have a `category` node as a direct child node under `product`:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t --if '/product/category' --else -f -nl ABC/*.xml
```

If you just want to detect files without any `category` nodes anywhere:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t --if '//category' --else -f -nl ABC/*.xml
```

In both these commands, `xmlstarlet` evaluates the given XPath expression.  If the expression evaluates to a set of at least one found node, then the `--if` test is *true* and nothing else happens.  Otherwise, the `--else` branch is evaluated and `-f -nl` causes the current filename to be outputted with a trailing newline character.

Assuming you want to do something to the files that lack the `category` node, the following sets up a loop that allows you to process the relevant files:

```bash
for xml in ABC/*.xml; do
    if ! xmlstarlet sel -t --if '/product/category' -nl "$xml" >/dev/null
    then
        # process "$xml" here
    fi
done
```

Installing `xmlstarlet` on macOS is best done via Homebrew.  The Homebrew package is called `xmlstarlet`, and the command will be called `xml` rather than `xmlstarlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like can do the work:

```
grep -vl '</category>' ABC/*
```

If you want to see also files w/o open tag you can try something like:

```
grep -vl 'category>' ABC/*
```

Comment: Your second would also match `<anothercategory>`, but neiher would match `<category attribute="value">` (I don't know if that's important here)

Comment: This would also match the search terms inside values of tags, attributes, CDATA sections, and comments.